# Random Numbers using Distributions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, probability, gaussian

I need to create a function that returns a vector of length n with values ranging from 0 to 1 (or similar, .01 to .99 works fine too) which follow a normal distribution with a specified mean mu and sd. That is, ~68% of the values in the vector fall within ±1 s.d. of the user-specified mean. The inputs of the function are thus n, mu, s.d. and one vector is returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I saw that, it's not quite the same thing. The range needs to be in (0,1) and it must encompass something around 98% of the data. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `randn`:

```
v = randn(1,n)*sd+mu;
```

The [**randn(1,n)**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) function will return an 1-by-n matrix containing pseudorandom values drawn from the standard normal distribution.

By multiplying it by sd and adding mu will give you a set of numbers that will be distributed normally with mean `mu` and standar deviation `sd`.

Comment: +1 See also `normrnd` (Statistics Toolbox), which basically calls `randn`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have stats toolbox (or I can't figure out how to start it). The code you used doesn't fit the numbers into a range of 0 to 1 (ex: hist(randn(1,500)*2+.5); ), and I'm trying to avoid black-boxes. 
Here's the code I have now that almost works, except the problem is that I cannot figure out the appropriate bounds for linspace. 
`xsigma=1;
xmu=.5*6*xsigma;

x=linspace(0,6*xsigma,1000); 
y=(xsigma*sqrt(2*pi))^-1 * exp(-((x-xmu).^2)/(2*xsigma^2));
plot(x/(6*xsigma),y);`
I thought 6-sigma would do it, but it doesn't. I want to capture 98% of the curve in (0,1).

Comment: See edits. If you use a mean of .5 and std of 2 you will obtain many values outside the 0 to 1 range.  if you want 98% of the values inside 0 to 1 you should use a mean of .5 and a std much smaller than 2 (try 0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misinterpreted your request and you dont want random numbers, but the Normal distribution curve evaluated between 0 and 1

The Gaussian equation or Normal distribution is:

```
x = (1:n)/n;
y = 1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-((x-mu).^2)/(2*sigma^2));
```

Since you want a vector of length = n, x should be that length too. So you could do it as above (it starts at 1/n and ends with 1).  Then you evaluate the Normal distribution on these values.